# How to install J2ME compatible platform/emulator in NetBeans IDE 6.7.1

Tags: netbeans, java-me, midp, netbeans6.7

I'm pretty new to J2ME development scene. And for that matter, have just recently installed, JDK 6 update 16 bundled with NetBeans 6.7.1 IDE and Sun WTK 2.5.2, on Ubuntu 9.04 machine.After going through some start up tutorials and basics, from various sites, I was eager to try some hands on experience by coding some 'Hello World' program. But to my dismay, I haven't been able to! After initial confusion, I'd installed 'Mobility' plugin for NetBeans IDE for J2ME development. But when I choose to create a new project, it turned out that, there is some error since now it says that 'No J2ME compatible platform/emulator found installed in NetBeans IDE'. I've searched through google to find a way to fix this issue but I couldn't find any solution on this matter.
  Please help me to fix this issue. Do I need to re-install the IDE? Am I missing out something? I've tried various ways but the IDE simply doesn't detect any platform on my machine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And I know that there is another IDE- Eclipse, which with its MTJ(Mobile Tools for Java) plugin can be used for J2ME development, but I'm more inclined to solve the issue with NetBeans right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in Netbeans:

Click menu-item: Tools->Java Platforms

Click button: Add platform...

Choose radio-button: Java ME MIDP Platform Emulator
  then click button: Next >

Find the directory where Netbeans 6.7.1 is installed
  then click OK

WTK2.5.2 that comes with Netbeans should be visible. Select it and click Next and follow further instructions.

If no WTK is found the dowload it, unpack it and try as above again but find the directory to the WTK this time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: with netbean 7.3 you need follow [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/quickstart.html) introduction